# Disabling "Remember password" for GKSU command

Tags: debian, password, gnome-keyring, gksu

I am using GKSU for switching user in my Linux terminal and I want to disable "Remember password" option in that Pop-up menu due to security reasons. I am not sure how to achieve that.

Mentioned below is the only trial i tried in the system, which did not work too.

```
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type bool --set /apps/gksu/save-to-keyring false
```

System config:
Os : Debian 8
Desktop Environment : LXDE

Command used for this operation :

```
gksu -u test /usr/bin/xterm
```

Attached screenshot for the same

[image]

I remember password option to be completely disabled

Answer (score 1):

Thought this might help someone

**gksu -a** works actually, was not able to get it through man pages

this link talks about the implementation : [gksu bug reference](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=314477#17)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the settings in gconf-editor.

```
gksu gconf-editor
```

once there set `/app/gksu/save-to-keyring to false` and set it mandatory.

**Edit**

Try this to disable gnome-keyring:

```
System-> Preferences-> Startup Applications
```

and uncheck

```
gnome-keyring-daemon
```

then log out and in and the application shouldn't start anymore. You can also unset the execute permissions of `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-manager`. You cannot simply uninstall it, because it would break programs that use it.

Comment: In my question I have executed the same command via gconftool-2, Do you find any error in that command ??

Comment: If it really doesn't work, why bother removing if you simply could add a master keyring password? Every time a saved password should be used you have to enter the master password to be able to access it.

Comment: Technically i do not want any keyring storage, I want user to enter password every time.

Comment: @Ragav edited my answer, that way you could disable the keyring.

Comment: I did try that  , changed execution permission for "gnome-keyring-manager" &  gnome-keyring . gksu still prompts with remember password and when i select "Remember password" for this session and reopen GKSU system hangs

Comment: Well that's probably because of the permissions. You can set them back (chmod 755) if you want, but where's the problem if you don't want to use it anyway?

Comment: This is customized OS install, where i installed system without GUI and after installation installed X and lxde-common. Is it anything to do with that ??

Comment: gksu -a works actually, was not able to get it through man this link talks about the implementation "https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=314477#17"