# Disabling Save for Session & Save to Keyring by LXDE way

Tags: debian, pam, lxde, lightdm

I am using minimal debian(jessie) with lxde-common installed for UI application view.

- This is in continuation of my previous question added littel bit clarity on my requirement.
  [My previous question reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374930/disabling-remember-password-for-gksu-command)

With this configuration I am trying to run "GKSU" with its configured shortcut key. it works as expected. However, the user password entry box for GKSU contains 2 option under remember password, which i want to disable completely across system

[image]

Option 1: **Save for session**

Option 2: **save for Keyring**

For my application use case I do not want these option. Need some guidance  for these setting changes

Mentioned are some of trials i have done from end

Command used for executions:

```
gksu -u test /usr/bin/xterm
```

Trail 1 : gconftool (Result : failed)

```
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type bool --set /apps/gksu/save-to-keyring false
```

Trail 2:  Disabling daemon execution permission

```
chmod +x $(type -p gnome-keyring) (Result : failed)
```

Trial 3: Commenting of pam_gnome_keyring under lightdm pam.d

In /etc/pam.d/lightdm two lines are commented (Result : "save for Keyring" was disabled)

```
#auth  optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
#session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

I am still not able to find a solution on disabling "Save for session" feature. Request some guidance